# Finding the line based on an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix

\begin{equation}
  A = \begin{pmatrix} 
     \cos\theta && \sin\theta \\
     \sin\theta && -\cos\theta
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

For every vector $v$ in $\Bbb R^2$, $v$, and $Av$ are symmetric about a line passing through the origin.

Taking $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ as the vector to be operated.

$$
   Av_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 
     \cos\theta && \sin\theta \\
     \sin\theta && -\cos\theta
  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} cos\theta \\ sin\theta \end{pmatrix} = R_1
$$

$$
   Av_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
     \cos\theta && \sin\theta \\
     \sin\theta && -\cos\theta
  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} sin\theta \\ -cos\theta \end{pmatrix} = R_2
$$

If I take $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ into the equation, the coordinates of $v_1, v_2$ becomes the following:

$$
  v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} \end{pmatrix}, v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\ -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} \end{pmatrix}
$$

This implies that $A$ is actually a rotation matrix that can transform every vector in $R^2$. However, this feels like that $R_1, R_2$ are possible points for different lines if I expressed their components with x and y:

$$
  sin\theta = cos\theta
$$

$$
  sin\theta = -cos\theta
$$

How could I find the line that is symmetric in this situation?

Comment: Question is bit unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the obscure question. I mean $A\vec v$ has a line that passes through origin $O(0, 0)$ as its symmetric axis, in this case, how can I find the line? It feels like the $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ is the symmetric line, but I am not sure how to find it in a standard way.

Comment: You still are not making sense. I believe you want a line through the origin so that *for every* $\vec v$, the vectors $\vec v$ and $A\vec v$ are symmetric about the line. Your answer will depend on $\theta$. Draw some pictures and do some exploring.

Comment: Equally unclear but if the line $L$ you want is the axis of the reflexion then $L=\{v\mid Av=v\}=$ the line which makes an angle $\theta/2$ with th $x$-axis.

Comment: Yes, for every $\vec v$ not just a certain $\vec v$. Let me revise the question.

Comment: Didn't my previous comment answer your question? If not, follow Ted's advice or look for some duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Find+axis+of+reflection   btw wrong spelling in my previous comment: refleCTion, not reflexion.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have tried to think from reflection. At first, I though it would be reflected around the y-axis which was wrong.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://e.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your reminder. I will try to avoid such question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$R = \left[
\begin{array}{cc} 
\cos \theta & - \sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array} \right]$$
and $$S = \left[
\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array} \right]$$

Clearly $A = RS$.

Now Let see what $R$ and $S$ means. Let us denote $$e_1 = \left[
\begin{array}{c} 
1\\
0
\end{array} \right] \quad e_2 = \left[
\begin{array}{c} 
0\\
1
\end{array} \right]$$

Here $S \, e_1 = e_1$ and $S \, e_2 = -e_2$. Hence, $S$ is a reflection around $x$-axis. Similarly $$R \, e_1  = \left[
\begin{array}{c} 
\cos \theta\\
\sin \theta
\end{array} \right] \quad R \, e_2 = \left[
\begin{array}{c} 
-\sin \theta\\
\cos \theta
\end{array} \right]$$ Hence $R$ is anti-clockwise rotation by $\theta$. So, axis of symmetry is the line $L$ making angle $\frac{\theta}{2}$ with positive $x$-axis.

The reason is $S \, L$ is the line making angle $-\frac{\theta}{2}$ with positive $x$-axis. And then rotating anti-clockwise by $\theta$ fixing $L$.

**Remark :** Also there is a rigorous way to explain it. We can show $$A = R_{\frac{\theta}{2}} S R_{-\frac{\theta}{2}}$$
where $R_{\phi}$ is anti-clockwise rotation by angle $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now understand a little bit about it. 

It looks like that R is an $\pi / 2$ rotation and its symmetric line is in the first quadrant. Since A = RS, the rotation is now reflected around the x-axis, hence, the rotation is now in the fourth quadrant. I am not certain if my explanation is correct, but it makes things a bit clearer.  

I think the line is $$ \begin{pmatrix} cos\dfrac{\theta}{2} \\ sin\dfrac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix} $$
Therefore $y = xtan\dfrac{\theta}{2}$.

Thank you for your thorough explanation!

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.